# Opencsv custom logic in parsing

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm using openCsv library cause it's very easy to use and I got all necessary functional. But now I need to use some custom logic except checking for correct types, columns and other usual things. I have a csv with columns `firstName`, `secondName`, `firstSalary`, `lastSalary` and others. I want to check that `firstDayOfWork` is less than `lastDayOfWork` in the process of parcing and add a new csvException if it is false. So, if now I'm parcing file

```
firstName,secondName,firstSalary,lastSalary
John, Doe, testtext, 5000
Alice, , 100, 5000
Harry, Smith, 400, 200
```

and processing a list of csvExcpetions I can get results of parcing like

```
Number of mistakes: 2
Line 1: Conversion of testtext to java.lang.Integer failed.
Line 2: Field 'secondName' is mandatory but no value was provided.
```

I want to something like

```
Number of mistakes: 3
Line 1: Conversion of testtext to java.lang.Integer failed.
Line 2: Field 'secondName' is mandatory but no value was provided.
Line 3: firstSalary cannot be more than lastSalary
```

Or some custom parcing logic like check if some field catch regexp, two fields at the same time greater than 0, etc.

I can firstly parce and convert it to beans and by the second cycle check my beans to these rules, but there are can be a lot of lines and it will take longer, so, I want to check it in the one process.

Can I get it by openCsv? And if yes, how? If no, what another tool I can use?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

based on [How to create a list of valid CSV records by logging the error of invalid record using OpenCsv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807420/how-to-create-a-list-of-valid-csv-records-by-logging-the-error-of-invalid-record/58824934#58824934), instead of throwing an IllegalArgumentException in the setters, you could:

1. create a BeanVerifier to verify the whole bean after creation;
2. throw a `CsvConstraintViolationException` on error;
3. add `.withThrowExceptions(false)` to the `CsvToBeanBuilder`;
4. Invoke `getCapturedExceptions()` to collect the validation errors.

The advantage of this solution is that you can collect the list of CSV exceptions as you wanted:

**Example**

```
final CsvToBean<EmployeeBean> csvToBean = 
    new CsvToBeanBuilder<EmployeeBean>(new FileReader("c:\\test.csv"))
        .withType(EmployeeBean.class)
        .withVerifier(new EmployeeSalaryVerifier())
        .withThrowExceptions(false)
        .build();

final List<EmployeeBeans> employees = csvToBean.parse();
List<CsvException> exceptions = parser.getCapturedExceptions();

// logging number of mistakes and, for each exception, its line number and message
logger.error("Number of Mistakes: {}", exceptions.size());
employees.getCapturedExceptions().stream().forEach(ex ->
    logger.error("Line {}: {}", ex.getLineNumber(), ex.getMessage(), ex));
```

**EmployeeBean**

```
public class EmployeeBean {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "First Name", required = true)
    private String firstName;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Last Name", required = true)
    private String lastName;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "First Salary" required = true)
    private Long firstSalary;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Last Salary")
    private Long lastSalary;

    // regular getters and setters, no validation here
}
```

**BeanVerifier**

```
public class EmployeeSalaryVerifier implements BeanVerifier<EmployeeBean> {

    @Override
    public boolean verifyBean(Employee bean) throws CsvConstraintViolationException {
    // check salary
    if (bean.getLastSalary() != null && bean.getFirstSalary().compareTo(bean.getLastSalary()) > 0) {
        throw new CsvConstraintViolationException("First Salary cannot be greater than Last Salary.");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have to write the line that has errors to another csv file, which I am able to do. But, the new csv doesn't have column names(headers). I am creating a list of String[] using employees.getCapturedExceptions(), and then using CSVWriter to write to a csv. Is there a way I can add column names(headers) using this approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While there is a request on the [todo/wish list](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/wiki/What's%20new/) for OpenCSV I don't think it will help you because it's about pre parsing validation

For what you want you should just add a check in your setters to throw an exception when the values are bad.  Here is my Bean and test.

```
public class SetterBean {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "First Name", required = true)
    private String firstName;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Last Name", required = true)
    private String lastName;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "First Salary")
    private Long firstSalary;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Last Salary")
    private Long lastSalary;

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstSalary(Long firstSalary) {
        if (lastSalary != null && (firstSalary.compareTo(lastSalary) > 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("First Salary cannot be greater than Last Salary.");
        }
        this.firstSalary = firstSalary;
    }

    public void setLastSalary(Long lastSalary) {
        if (firstSalary != null && (lastSalary.compareTo(firstSalary) < 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Last Salary cannot be less than First Salary.");
        }
        this.lastSalary = lastSalary;
    }
}

public class SetterValidationTest {
    private static final String HEADER = "First Name,Last Name,First Salary,Last Salary\n";

    CsvToBean<SetterBean> csvToBean;

    @Test
    public void normalData() {
        String data = HEADER + "First, Last, 1, 2";
        csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<SetterBean>(new StringReader(data))
                .withType(SetterBean.class)
                .build();
        List<SetterBean> beans = csvToBean.parse();
        assertEquals(1, beans.size());
    }

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void firstGTLast() {
        String data = HEADER + "First, Last, 2, 1";
        csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<SetterBean>(new StringReader(data))
                .withType(SetterBean.class)
                .build();
        List<SetterBean> beans = csvToBean.parse();
    }
}
```

And here is the result.

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.assignValueToField(AbstractBeanField.java:192)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.setFieldValue(AbstractBeanField.java:159)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processField(ProcessCsvLine.java:140)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:126)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:82)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.assignValueToField(AbstractBeanField.java:187)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last Salary cannot be less than First Salary.
    at integrationTest.BeanTests.SetterBean.setLastSalary(SetterBean.java:33)
    ... 12 more
```

Hope that helps.

Scott Conway :)