# How to create a list of valid CSV records by logging the error of invalid record using OpenCsv?

Tags: java, csv, parsing, iterator

In my CSV I have inconsistent data so I have to log the error while iterating record and want to create a list of POJO of valid CSV records. I am using OpenCsv to process the CSV file.
I have added try-catch block to log the error if there is any but at **while(iterator.hasNext())** there is the exception/error as next record has some incorrect formatted data.

So how to log the error and continue to process the next record?

```java
List<UserProvisioning> list = new ArrayList<>();
CsvToBean<UserProvisioning> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<UserProvisioning>(
        new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath())).withType(UserProvisioning.class)
                .withIgnoreQuotations(true).build();
Iterator<UserProvisioning> iterator = beans.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    try {
        UserProvisioning userProvisioning = (UserProvisioning) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(userProvisioning.getFIRST_NAME());
        list.add(userProvisioning);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        logger.error("Error occured...)
    }
}
```

If I use **.withThrowExceptions(false)** I can process all valid records but not able to log the error.

**Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: Number of data fields does not match number of headers.
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:101)
    at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean$CsvToBeanIterator.readLineWithPossibleError(CsvToBean.java:551)
    at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean$CsvToBeanIterator.readSingleLine(CsvToBean.java:571)
    at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean$CsvToBeanIterator.next(CsvToBean.java:591)
    at com.apds.partner.nycdoc.main.NycDocApplication.main(NycDocApplication.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: Number of data fields does not match number of headers.
    at com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.verifyLineLength(HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java:110)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.populateNewBean(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:313)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:132)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:85)
    ... 9 more
```

How to create a list of valid csv records by logging the error of invalid record using OpenCsv?

As per my understanding iterator.hasNext() tries to check whether next element is present or not by mapping csv record column to POJO fields and as there is invalid data in csv record headers count do not matches record files hence error `java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: Number of data fields does not match number of headers.`

**EDIT**

OpenCSV version 4.6

Sample Records:

```
ID1,ID2,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,BIRTH_DATE,HA1,HA2,TYPE,STATUS,DT,LEVEL
3491905454,04572538R,L,L,1964-08-01,RNDC,M4SL,GP  ,DEP,,
3491901894,04353902J,TO,TO,1962-10-20,AMKC,QUAD-L3,GP  ,DE,,
3491903493,01940960Y,JAM"ES,TO,1985-03-12,GRVC,13A,PS  ,DPV,,
8951900652,08661334Z,"ROT,TEST",RODRIGUEZ,1971-09-17,AMKC,1 TOP,GP  ,DE,,
4411801431,02661015Y,CET,TEC,1964-06-21,RNDC,M4NU,GP  ,DE,,
9801900155,06467584H,RAT,BAT,1969-12-01,GRVC,8A,GP  ,DE,,GSL3
```

4th and 5th lines has inconsistant data

Comment: Try wrap another try catch block around `while (iterator.hasNext())` @Sagar

Comment: @hydroPenguin then again it will log the error for that line and stop iterating the loop

Comment: It is interesting behavior. Supposedly `hasNext()` shouldn't throw any exceptions, and all exceptions thrown is handled by following try catch block, which you only log it not throw it. Best bet is using the approach that I suggested a while ago and posted by another answer, `getCapturedExceptios()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Add to `CsvToBeanBuilder` `.withThrowExceptions(false)` to
   ignore runtime exceptions
2. Parse the bean
3. Invoke `getCapturedExceptions()` to get all exceptions that
   would have been thrown during the import, but were suppressed
4. Iterate through `CsvException` array (after parsing) and log
   exceptions

See the code snippet below:

```java
final CsvToBean<UserProvisioning> beans = 
    new CsvToBeanBuilder<UserProvisioning>(new FileReader("c:\\test.csv"))
        .withType(UserProvisioning.class)
        .withIgnoreQuotations(true)
        .withThrowExceptions(false) //1
        .build();

    final List<UserProvisioning> users = beans.parse();//2
    users.stream().forEach((user) -> {
        logger.info("Parsed data:" + user.toString());
    });

    beans.getCapturedExceptions().stream().forEach((exception) -> { //3
        logger.error("Inconsistent data:" + 
                      String.join("", exception.getLine()), exception);//4
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Oleks, for the solution. I have been looking for a solution for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the error is thrown by `CsvToBean<UserProvisioning> beans = ...`

Quick read on [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/bugs/196/), I think it might be caused by some errors on your header, in CSV file.

Comment: No. Error is at while(iterator.hasNext()). I did debug the program

Comment: em.. then it is probably one of the records that is not compliant with the header? Your code seems to be correct for handling exception, it is not supposed to throw it because you only log it. Is your `logger` working fine elsewhere?

Comment: I just found out there is a method to get exceptions. Basically you do `withThrowExceptions(false)`; declare a list of exception by calling `getCapturedExceptions()` on `beans` (details [here](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBean.html#getCapturedExceptions--).) When you iterate through `beans`, check if the list is empty, if it is not that means exception occurred, log it at this time, and remove the logged exception.

Comment: I have to log the error for the invalid record. Using withThrowExceptions(false) it does not throw an exception.

Comment: Okay then this method doesn't work. Again is your `logger` working fine elsewhere? What logging framework are you using? log4j?

Comment: @Sagar iterator.hasNext() can not throw CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException by declaration.
Does the csv file have a header? Try to add withSkipLines(1).

Comment: @Oleksandr please check the edit in question description

Comment: @Sagar 1. What is OpenCSV version? 2. Could you pls post any inconsistent record example and csv header if it is available.