# OpenCSV: file as a stream of records and exceptions

Tags: java, spring, opencsv, reactor

I have such a method:

```
public <T> Flux<T> deserialize(MultipartFile multipartFile, Class<T> type) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(multipartFile.getInputStream()));
    MappingStrategy<T> ms = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
    ms.setType(type);
    CsvToBean<T> cb = new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(reader)
            .withType(type)
            .withMappingStrategy(ms)
            .build();
    return Flux.fromStream(cb.stream());
}
```

which takes multipart file and returns a flux based on stream of records from this CSV file. **Question**: is there any way to get a stream of something like Either<Class, Exception>?

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807420/how-to-create-a-list-of-valid-csv-records-by-logging-the-error-of-invalid-record) but the answer uses `.parse()` which would not be appropriate for big CSV files.